# How to find harmonic functions satisfying boundary conditions, in polar coordinates.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

In *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis Engineering, Science, and Mathematics* by Saff and Snider, problem 2.5.13 is

> Find a function harmonic inside the wedge bounded by the nonegative $x$-axis and
> the half-line $y = x \ \ (x \ge 0)$ that goes to zero on these sides but is not identically
> zero. [HINT: See Prob. 12.]

And problem 12 is

> Prove that if $r$ and $\theta$ are polar coordinates, then the functions $r^n \cos n\theta$ and $r^n \sin n\theta$,
> where $n$ is an integer, are harmonic as functions of $x$ and $y$. [HINT: Recall De
> Moivre's formula.]

I know that $r^n\cos n \theta = \Re \{[re^{i\theta}]^n\}=\Re z^n$, and I think since $z^n$ is analytic in this domain then its components are harmonic.

What I don't see is how to relate this to problem 13.  I know that one solution to this problem is $z^4$ but I don't see how this comes from these facts about polar coordinates.  So although I know a solution to problem 13, I'm not sure how one is supposed to find it by the hint.  I guess somehow we're setting $n=4$, but why?  Is $\theta = \pi/4$ and $\theta=0$ to get the two rays from the origin?  Even if I can guess at superficial connections I can't begin to see the rigorous logic connecting these.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you are looking for $n$ such that $\sin(n\pi/4)=0$, so $n=4$ will do.  Take $f(r,\theta)=r^4 \sin(4\theta)$.